# Java - How to encoded MAC decoded font information

Tags: java, macos, clipboard, encode, checkstyle

I'm trying to get font information from **Clipboard** using **MAC**.Below is the code for getting value from **Clipboard**.

**CODE**

```
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
DataFlavor dfRTF = new DataFlavor("text/rtf", "Rich Formatted Text");
DataFlavor dfTxt = DataFlavor.stringFlavor;
boolean hasTransferableRTFText = (contents != null)
                && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(dfRTF);
boolean hasTransferableTxtText = (contents != null)
                && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(dfTxt);
if (hasTransferableRTFText) {
try {
result = streamToString((InputStream)contents.getTransferData(dfRTF));
System.out.println("dfRTF "+result);
} catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
} else if (hasTransferableTxtText) {
try {
result = (String)contents.getTransferData(dfTxt);
System.out.println("dfTxt "+result);
} catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

and the code returned **MAC** decoded value as below:

```
dfRTF {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf360
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\ql\qnatural\pardirnatural

\f0\b\fs24 \cf0 Hello WORLD}
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf360
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\ql\qnatural\pardirnatural

\f0\b\fs24 \cf0 Hello WORLD}
```

I know that `\f0\b\fs24 \cf0 Hello WORLD}` contains the font information where `\b` means the its **`BOLD`**.
How do I encoded it to get that particular value, for an example I want to know whether it **BOLDED or NO.** Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undestand well what you need, you can try to convert it to html and use a library like jsoup to extract the needed information.

Here is an example to extract to first bold text found in the clipboard

```
package rtfTest;


import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.EditorKit;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;



public class TestRtf{ 
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        TestRtf t = new TestRtf();
        t.readClipboard() ;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    static String streamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }

    public static String rtfToHtml(Reader rtf) throws IOException { // From http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/136483/Java-How-to-convert-RTF-into-HTML
        JEditorPane p = new JEditorPane();
        p.setContentType("text/rtf");
        EditorKit kitRtf = p.getEditorKitForContentType("text/rtf");
        try {
            kitRtf.read(rtf, p.getDocument(), 0);
            kitRtf = null;
            EditorKit kitHtml = p.getEditorKitForContentType("text/html");
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();
            kitHtml.write(writer, p.getDocument(), 0, p.getDocument().getLength());
            return writer.toString();
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void readClipboard () {
        String result;
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
        DataFlavor dfRTF = new DataFlavor("text/rtf", "Rich Formatted Text");
        DataFlavor dfTxt = DataFlavor.stringFlavor;

        boolean hasTransferableRTFText = (contents != null)
                && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(dfRTF);
        boolean hasTransferableTxtText = (contents != null)
                && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(dfTxt);
        if (hasTransferableRTFText) {
            try {
                // result = streamToString((InputStream)contents.getTransferData(dfRTF));
                // Convert rtf to html 
                result = rtfToHtml(new StringReader(streamToString((InputStream)contents.getTransferData(dfRTF))));
                // Example of text extraction from html
                // Parse html
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(result);
                // Select first bold text
                Element firstBoldElt = doc.select("b").first(); 
                String firstBoldText = firstBoldElt.text(); 

                System.out.println(firstBoldText);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (hasTransferableTxtText) {
            try {
                result = (String)contents.getTransferData(dfTxt);
                System.out.println("dfTxt "+ result);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }}}
```

Comment: any idea  how we can loop the `Document doc = Jsoup.parse(result);`. How do i check bold for entire element instead the first bold text.?

Answer (score 0):

For identify the all bold element you can use doc.outerHtml() method which return whole html.

Suppose in my clipboard i have copy below data like

**Bold1
Bold2**
Bold3
**Bold4**

now when you use doc.outerHtml() you will get below response

```
<html><head><style><!--p.DefaultaParagraphaFont {bold:normal;italic:;underline:;}--></style></head><body><p class="default"> <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri"> <b>Bold1</b> </span> </p> <p class="default"> <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri"> <b>Bold2</b> </span> </p> <p class="default"> <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri"> Bold3 </span> </p> <p class="default"> <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri"> <b>Bold4</b> </span> </p></body></html>
```

So now you just need to put some parsing logic for reading bold element.

Comment: I need for java code since Im using java swing for my development. any how I got hint from @fazerty. Thanks